Error when adding allUsers permissions in Google Cloud Functions
Access the functional address you received after deployment (https://region-id.cloudfunctions.net/api) 'Error: Forbidden'
The error "Your client does not have permission to get URL /api from this server."
I'm used the first generation method that we checked in the official Google Cloud document.
1.Go to the Google Cloud console:
2.Click the checkbox next to the receiving function. (Don't click on the function itself.)
3.Click Permissions at the top of the screen. The Permissions panel opens.
4.Click Add principal.
5.In the New principals field, type allUsers.
6.Select the role Cloud Functions > Cloud Functions Invoker from the Select a role drop-down menu.
7.In response to the dialog, click Allow public access.

However, during the application process, the message that it failed was printed as follows.
IAM policy update failed
Invalid state 'projects/project-name/locations/region/functions/api': The operation failed with precondition error. This is usually because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution
Request ID: 11245686184098564410

What should I do in this case?

Is it a cloud function gen1 or gen2?

It is a cloud function gen1.
